# Build&Release Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ms-release-management

When I commit a project to vsts to do Build Automation

it's have a error

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

but my project it's can work on local with vs

have anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add NuGet Restore task to your build/release definition.

1. Change version to 0.*
2. Path to solution or packages.config: ***.sln
3. Select Restore for Installation type

Answer (score 1):

Your build can't find a referenced Assembly. This could be because of missing the nuget restore build step (look at the other answer here) or because of some missing entry in your repository of this particular build.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to add packages.config file to the source control.